# Hello.js page refresh on re-login

Tags: javascript, twitter-oauth, hello.js

I am using hello.js to log in with twitter on a react app.

```
hello.init({
  twitter: 'II7hpGaWFZ1n2dbpGzr59bxko',
});
```

I do have the app registered on https://auth-server.herokuapp.com

When my page first loads, it presents a login form.  User can click button to login with twitter, hello.js opens a popup and authenticates.  User returns to homepage and secure content is displayed

```
<button className="button button-red primary" name="login"
   onClick={(e)=>{this.handleTwitterLogin(e)}}>
      <i className="icon-twitter float-left"></i>Continue with Twitter
</button>

handleTwitterLogin = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
  hello.login('twitter', auth=>{
    console.log('requesting twitter auth')
    hello('twitter').api('me')
      .then( result=>{
        this.props.actions.login('twitter')
        this.props.actions.updateUser({
          username: result.name,
          screen_name: result.screen_name,
          image: result.profile_image_url_https
        })
      this.props.history.push('/')
    })
  })
}
```

So far, so good.  If the user logs out, I log them out of twitter, log out of my app and redirect to home page:

```
logout = () => {
  hello.logout('twitter', ()=>{
  this.props.actions.logout()
  this.props.history.push('/')
  })
}
```

Home page now shows the login form again because user is logged out.  However if the user clicks the "login with twitter" button again, it appears that the page is refreshed and the URL changes from `/` to `/?login=` and the button's onClick handler `handleTwitterLogin = (event) =>` function is NOT called.  Clicking that button a second time initiates the login process as expected.  I cannot figure out what code is being called to reload the page or how to debug it.

Comment: I'm not sure i can get it on jsfiddle with react/redux/etc.  will try to deploy to glitch

Comment: Steps to reproduce: 
1. https://fixation.glitch.me/
2. login with twitter
3. click profile icon in top right
4. click `...` icon to logout
5. click login with twitter button (should login, but instead refreshes page)

Comment: I notice it's in a form, and since I don't have access to the JS. I assume this is doing a postback. Are you using `e.preventDefault()` in your method that gets called when they click the button?

Comment: yes, i'm calling `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` in the `handleTwitterLogin` function (see above)...as far as I can tell the form is not being submitted.